# Using One Grouping to Color Lines, Another Grouping to Determine Line Style with `ggplot2`

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given these data:

```
population <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
group <- rep(c("Control", "Control", "Experimental", "Experimental"), 2)
wave <- rep(c("Pretest", "Posttest"), 4)
outcome <- c(2.4, 2.5, 2.4, 3.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 3.4)
ci <- rep(c(.3, .4), 4)
df <- data.frame(population, group, wave, outcome, ci)
```

I would like to produce a line graph similar to this:

[image: Example Figure]

In which:

- One grouping variable (e.g., `Population`) determines the line / dot color,
- And another grouping variable (e.g., `Group`) determines the line style.

I have had some success with:

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = wave, y = outcome, color = interaction(population, group), shape = group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = outcome - ci, ymax = outcome + ci), width = .15, position = pd) +
  geom_line(position = pd, size = 2) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size=3.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 23))
```

But you will quickly see where my ability and research into it thus far fails to garner useful returns:

[image]

TYIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could help you, as long you want to see differences between pre and post test:

```
library(ggplot2)

#Data
population <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
group <- rep(c("Control", "Control", "Experimental", "Experimental"), 2)
wave <- rep(c("Pretest", "Posttest"), 4)
outcome <- c(2.4, 2.5, 2.4, 3.4, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 3.4)
ci <- rep(c(.3, .4), 4)
df <- data.frame(population, group, wave, outcome, ci)
df$wave <- factor(df$wave,levels = c('Pretest','Posttest'))

#Plot
pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = wave, y = outcome, color = interaction(population, group), shape = group,
               group=interaction(population, group))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = outcome - ci, ymax = outcome + ci), width = .15, position = pd,size=1) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=group),size=1) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size=3.5)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]